# How can I switch between pdflatex and xelatex conversion in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: macos, latex, sublime-text-2, texlive, xetex

I often switch between compiling "classic" LaTeX and XeTeX documents.

Sublime Text 2 has a package called [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) that allows you to build LaTeX documents via a simple <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. Neat.

The build file `LaTeX.sublime-build` obviously exists in the standard package folder, and you can copy it to your `User` folder to customize it. Here, it allows you to change the arguments given to `latexmk`, namely to switch from `pdflatex` to `xelatex`, for example like this:

```
"cmd": ["latexmk", "-cd",
  //"-e", "\\$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
  "-e", "\\$pdflatex = 'xelatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S'",
  //"-silent",
  "-f", "-pdf"],
```

Now, it's very tedious having to do that every time I open up another document – open my build preferences, comment out the one line, save, etc.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to switch the engine

- **… automatically** – TextMate for example somehow does that, and I can compile both LaTeX documents and XeTeX documents with a simple <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, although the TextMate configuration is set to `pdflatex`. Maybe it's some `latexmk.pl`-fu, I don't know.
- **… with a simple keyboard shortcut or setting** – Maybe pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> or similar. This would then toggle between `pdflatex` and `xelatex` building.

How could I set that up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Note:** LaTeXTools for Sublime Text now supports automatic engine detection if your file starts with `%!TEX program = <program>`, where `<program>` is any of `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`. The below instructions are only necessary if you need to manually switch engines for whatever reasons.

---

Take the `LaTeX.sublime-build` file in the `LaTeXTools` folder under `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages` and copy it to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/`, but do it twice and give those files the following name:

- `LaTeX.sublime-build.latex`
- `LaTeX.sublime-build.xetex`

Change the files to use the `pdflatex` for LaTeX and `xelatex` engines for XeTeX, respectively (as seen in the question).

Then, create a new plugin through *Tools » New Plugin…* (saving it as `switch.py` to the location above):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os, shutil, filecmp

class SwitchCommand(sublime_plugin.ApplicationCommand):
  def run(self):
    folder = os.path.expanduser( \
        '~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/')
    latex_src = folder + 'LaTeX.sublime-build.latex'
    xetex_src = folder + 'LaTeX.sublime-build.xetex'
    dest = folder + 'LaTeX.sublime-build'

    if filecmp.cmp(dest, latex_src):
      sublime.status_message("Switching to XeTeX")
      shutil.copy(xetex_src, dest)
    else:
      sublime.status_message("Switching to LaTeX")
      shutil.copy(latex_src, dest)
```

And create a keyboard shortcut for it in *Preferences » Key Bindings – User*:

```
[ {
  "keys": ["super+shift+x"], "command": "switch"
} ]
```

You can also add this to your menu by adding the `Main.sublime-menu` file to your `User` package:

```
[ {
    "id":"tools", "children":
    [ {
        "command": "switch",
        "caption": "Switch between LaTeX/XeTeX"
      }
    ]
} ]
```

This will now compare the currently active build file with the build settings needed for XeTeX and LaTeX and switch them if necessary.

[image]

This could sure use some improvement, but it works for the moment.

Comment: Works like a charm, except that LaTeXTools doesn't seem to be giving precedence to `LaTeX.sublime-build` in my user packages folder. Quite odd...

Comment: Do you make a full copy of the default `LaTeX.sublime-build`, which you then modify, or just include the relevant `osx` portion?

Comment: First of all thanks for the edits. I did a full copy of the default file and modified them accordingly. What I found out though was that XeLaTeX compiles all LaTeX sources fine, at least on all of the files I tested. Maybe there's a fallback somewhere in the background?

Comment: Copying and modifying the full default file solved my issue. Interesting that using just XeLaTeX is sufficient for both. I'll check this out in the future as it'll definitely be better than having to switch compilers. Thanks for the prompt response!